# ChartJS showing incorrect data on the X-Axes

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli, chart.js

I require assistance with ChartJS, it is showing data for months that do not even exist in my MySQL database. I have data for August and September in the database, there is no data for the rest of the months, why does it show data for the other months?

Here is an UPDATED view of the dashboard with the ChartJS

[Ecems Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfVSR.png)

Here is my MySQL Table Contents:

[MySQL Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA3Xl.png)

My index.php file:

```
<?php include 'settings.php'; //include settings ?>

<body class="crm_body_bg">
<!-- main content part here -->
<section class="main_content dashboard_part">
        <!-- menu  -->
    <div class="container-fluid no-gutters">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 p-0 ">
                <div class="header_iner d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="sidebar_icon d-lg-none">
                        <i class="ti-menu"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="serach_field-area">
                            <div class="search_inner">
                                <form action="#">
                                    <div class="search_field">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search here..." >
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit"> <img src="img/icon/icon_search.svg" alt=""> </button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="header_right d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="profile_info">
                             <img src="../../img/<?php $ufunc->UserName(); //Show name who is in session user?>.jpg" alt="#">
                            <div class="profile_info_iner">
                                <div class="profile_author_name">
                                <h5><?php $ufunc->UserName(); //Show name who is in session user?></h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="profile_info_details">
                                    <a href="#">My Profile </a>
                                    <a href="#">Settings</a>
                                   <a href="../../includes/logout.php">Logout</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/ menu  -->
    <div class="main_content_iner ">
        <div class="container-fluid p-0 sm_padding_15px">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="dashboard_header mb_50">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="dashboard_header_title">
                                    <h3>ECEMS v2.0 Administration Dashboard</h3>
                                    <h6>Logged in as: <?php $ufunc->UserName(); //Show name who is in session user?></h6>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="dashboard_breadcam text-right">
                                    <p><a href="#">Dashboard</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                    <div class="white_box mb_30">
                        <div class="box_header">
                            <div class="main-title">
                                <h3 class="mb_25" >General Recyclables Processing Overview</h3>
                            </div>
                           
                        </div>
            
                                    <canvas id="general-recyclables"></canvas>
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
                  
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                    <div class="white_box mb_30">
                        <div class="box_header">
                            <div class="main-title">
                                <h3 class="mb_25" >Printed Circuit Boards Processing Overview</h3>
                            </div>
                        
                        </div>
            
                                    <canvas id="general-recyclables2"></canvas>
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
                   <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                    <div class="white_box mb_30">
                        <div class="box_header">
                            <div class="main-title">
                                <h3 class="mb_25" >Targets for <?php echo date('F Y'); ?></h3>
                            </div>
                          
                        </div>
            <h3>Target: 12000KG</h3>
            <h3>Current Value:  <?php
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=ecemsmaster;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'ecemsmaster', 'ecemsmaster');
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//The COUNT SQL statement that we will use.
$sql = "SELECT SUM(subgrade ++ castaluminium ++ copper ++ stainlesssteel ++ plastic ++ batteries ++ brass ++ cables ++ lowgradePCB ++ mediumgradePCB ++ highgradePCB) AS num FROM daily_recyclables where MONTH(date)=MONTH(curdate());";

//Prepare the COUNT SQL statement.
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);

//Execute the COUNT statement.
$stmt->execute();

//Fetch the row that MySQL returned.
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//The $row array will contain "num". Print it out.
echo $row['num'];
?> KG</h3>
            <h3>Over/Under Target: -1000KG</h3>
            
            <br>
           
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                    <div class="white_box mb_30">
                        <div class="box_header">
                            <div class="main-title">
                                <h3 class="mb_25" >Previous Month</h3>
                            </div>
                          
                        </div>
            <h3>Target: 12000KG</h3>
            <h3>Previous Value:  <?php
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=ecemsmaster;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'ecemsmaster', 'ecemsmaster');
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//The COUNT SQL statement that we will use.
$sql = "SELECT SUM(subgrade ++ castaluminium ++ copper ++ stainlesssteel ++ plastic ++ batteries ++ brass ++ cables ++ lowgradePCB ++ mediumgradePCB ++ highgradePCB) AS num FROM daily_recyclables where MONTH(date)=MONTH(curdate())-1;";

//Prepare the COUNT SQL statement.
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);

//Execute the COUNT statement.
$stmt->execute();

//Fetch the row that MySQL returned.
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//The $row array will contain "num". Print it out.
echo $row['num'];
?> KG</h3>
            <h3>Over/Under Target: -1000KG</h3>
            
            <br>
           
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
<?php
require '../../includes/global_footer.html'; //include Global Footer
?>
```

Here is my **UPDATED** linegraph.js file based on **rustyBucketBay** answer 15/10/2021

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url : "http://www.ecems.co.za/ecemsv2/user/admin/data.php",
    type : "POST",
    success : function(data){
      console.log(data);

     
      var date = [];
      var subgrade_material = [];
       var castaluminium_material = [];
      var copper_material = [];
       var stainlesssteel_material = [];
        var plastic_material = [];
         var batteries_material = [];
          var brass_material = [];
           var cables_material = [];
           

      for(var i in data) {
        date.push("" + data[i].date);
        subgrade_material.push(data[i].subgrade);
        castaluminium_material.push(data[i].castaluminium);
         copper_material.push(data[i].copper);
          stainlesssteel_material.push(data[i].stainlesssteel);
           plastic_material.push(data[i].plastic);
            batteries_material.push(data[i].batteries);
            brass_material.push(data[i].brass);
              cables_material.push(data[i].cables);
             
      }
var barChartData = {
    labels: [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December"
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Subgrade",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(189,55,220,0.5)",
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200]
      },
       {
        label: "Cast Aluminium",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(89,155,120,0.5)",
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200]
      },
      {
        label: "Copper",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(100,105,20,0.5)",
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200]
      },
       {
        label: "Stainless Steel",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(2,15,12,0.5)",
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200]
      },
       {
        label: "Brass",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(99,99,120,0.5)",
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200]
      },
      // {
      //   label: "Copper",
      //   backgroundColor: "rgba(129,155,20,0.5)",
      //   data: copper_material
      // },
      // {
      //   label: "Stainless Steel",
      //   backgroundColor: "rgba(29,255,55,0.5)",
      //   data: stainlesssteel_material
      // },
      // {
      //   label: "Brass",
      //   backgroundColor: "rgba(0,155,45,0.5)",
      //   data: brass_material
      // }
    ]
  };

var ctx = document.getElementById("general-recyclables").getContext("2d");
var myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barChartData,
   
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: "General Recyclables Overview By Month"
        },
      
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true
            }]
        }
    }
});

   
      
      
    },
    
    error : function(data) {

    }
    
  });
  
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url : "http://www.ecems.co.za/ecemsv2/user/admin/data.php",
    type : "POST",
    success : function(data){
      console.log(data);

     
      var date = [];
      var lowgradePCB = [];
       var mediumgradePCB = [];
      var highgradePCB = [];
   

      for(var i in data) {
        date.push("" + data[i].date);
        lowgradePCB.push(data[i].lowgradePCB);
        mediumgradePCB.push(data[i].mediumgradePCB);
        highgradePCB.push(data[i].highgradePCB);
       
      }
var barChartData = {
    labels: [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December"
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Low Grade PCB",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(27,27,235,0.5)",
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200]
      },
       {
        label: "Medium Grade PCB",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(20,170,235,0.5)",
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200]
      },
      {
        label: "High Grade PCB",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(20,235,34,0.5)",
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200]
      },
    
    ]
  };

var ctx = document.getElementById("general-recyclables2").getContext("2d");
var myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barChartData,
   
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Printed Circuit Board Processing Overview"
        },
      
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true
            }]
        }
    }
});

   
      
      
    },
    
    error : function(data) {

    }
    
  });
  
});
```

Here is my data.php file:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

//database
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'REDACTED');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'REDACTED');
define('DB_NAME', 'REDACTED');

//get mysqliection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$mysqli){
    die("connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT recID,date,subgrade,castaluminium,copper,stainlesssteel,plastic,batteries,brass,cables,lowgradePCB,mediumgradePCB,highgradePCB FROM daily_recyclables");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close mysqliection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);


?>
```

Comment: seems you are passign to the graph the subgrade and lowgradePCB values directly (deduced from the graph images). You would need to arrange the data with the corresponding agrupation by month, so that the data array corresponds with the label array `["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]` for each index of the data array

Comment: @rustyBucketBay would you be able to assist me with a proper example. I am literally new at this and been following hundreds of tutorials, but if i can get a proper example based on my code, then my learning curve will be complete :D

Comment: see answer below to explain what I mean

Comment: @rustyBucketBay Please see my edit. Think im going in the right direction. Just struggling with getting my actual data to display, not the hard coded numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se for example your simplified graph in the snippet below. The data for each of the month is allocated by index to the graph.

labels: ["January", "February",....]
data: [100, 200, ....]

So 100 is for january and 200 for february and so on.

What I mean, is that you need to pass an array with the data in the array already grouped by month either the array "hardcoded" by you, or make the corresponding arrangements with code to retrieve that array using the date field of your database

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>

<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
<script>
  var barChartData = {
    labels: [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December"
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Subgrade",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(189,55,220,0.5)",
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100]
      }
      // {
      //   label: "Cast Aluminium",
      //   backgroundColor: "rgba(29,155,220,0.5)",
      //   data: castaluminium_material
      // },
      // {
      //   label: "Copper",
      //   backgroundColor: "rgba(129,155,20,0.5)",
      //   data: copper_material
      // },
      // {
      //   label: "Stainless Steel",
      //   backgroundColor: "rgba(29,255,55,0.5)",
      //   data: stainlesssteel_material
      // },
      // {
      //   label: "Brass",
      //   backgroundColor: "rgba(0,155,45,0.5)",
      //   data: brass_material
      // }
    ]
  };

  var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
  var myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "bar",
    data: barChartData,
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "General Recyclables Overview By Month"
      },
      tooltips: {
        mode: "label"
        // callbacks: {
        //   label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
        //     var corporation = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
        //     var valor =
        //       data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
        //     var total = 0;
        //     for (var i = 0; i < data.datasets.length; i++)
        //       total += data.datasets[i].data[tooltipItem.index];
        //     if (tooltipItem.datasetIndex != data.datasets.length - 1) {
        //       return (
        //         corporation +
        //         " : KG" +
        //         valor.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,")
        //       );
        //     } else {
        //       return [
        //         corporation +
        //           " :" +
        //           valor.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,"),
        //         "Total : " + total + " KG"
        //       ];
        //     }
        //   }
        // }
      },
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        xAxes: [
          {
            stacked: true
          }
        ],
        yAxes: [
          {
            stacked: true
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });

  var barChartData = {
    labels: [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December"
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Low Grade PCB",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(189,55,220,0.5)",
        data: lowgradePCB_material
      },
      {
        label: "Medium Grade PCB",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(29,155,220,0.5)",
        data: mediumgradePCB_material
      },
      {
        label: "Copper",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(129,155,20,0.5)",
        data: highgradePCB_material
      }
    ]
  };

  var ctx = document.getElementById("general-recyclables2").getContext("2d");
  var myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "bar",
    data: barChartData,
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Printed Circuit Board Processing"
      },
      tooltips: {
        mode: "label",
        callbacks: {
          label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
            var corporation = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
            var valor =
              data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.datasets.length; i++)
              total += data.datasets[i].data[tooltipItem.index];
            if (tooltipItem.datasetIndex != data.datasets.length - 1) {
              return (
                corporation +
                " : KG" +
                valor.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,")
              );
            } else {
              return [
                corporation +
                  " :" +
                  valor.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,"),
                "Total : " + total + " KG"
              ];
            }
          }
        }
      },
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        xAxes: [
          {
            stacked: true
          }
        ],
        yAxes: [
          {
            stacked: true
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I think im getting it, please check EDIT - Here is my **UPDATED** linegraph.js file based on **rustyBucketBay** answer 15/10/2021. So i see what you are saying now. But when i replace the number values with my values, castaluminium_material for example. nothing displays.

Comment: dont know why is not rendering now. You got a working example in the answer. Depart from a simple case and try to render that. Then render your desired info

Comment: Cant get it to work :(. Using your example with data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100] yes it works, but with my own data from MYSQL, not working. I am going to accept your answer as the answer and post another question.

Answer (score 0):

try modify Date format issues，
check date `Date.UTC()`